# Sensu with sensu-plugins-slack no sending message

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, monitoring, slack-api, slack, sensu

On my Sensu server (non-enterprise) I first installed the https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-slack plugin via `sudo sensu-install -p slack`.

My configuration files located on my sensu server are as following.

`/etc/sensu/conf.d/handler_config_slack.json`:

```
{
    "handlers": {
        "slack": {
            "type": "pipe",
            "command": "/usr/local/bin/handler-slack.rb",
            "severites": ["critical", "unknown"]
        }
    },
    "slack": {
        "webhook_url": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/...",
        "username": "sensu",
        "channel": "#ops",
        "timeout": 10
    }
}
```

`/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json`:

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "sensu-server-client-test",
    "address": "x.x.x.x",
    "subscriptions": [
      "test"
    ],
    "keepalive": {
        "thresholds": {
            "warning": 30,
            "critical": 40
        },
        "handlers": ["slack"],
        "refresh": 300
    }
  }
}
```

And the sensu remote client servers file `/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json`:

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "sensu-client-test",
    "address": "x.x.x.x",
    "subscriptions": [
      "test"
    ],
    "keepalive": {
        "thresholds": {
            "warning": 30,
            "critical": 40
        },
        "handlers": ["slack"],
        "refresh": 300
    }
  }
}
```

`/var/log/sensu/sensu-srver.log`:

```
{"timestamp":"2016-02-21T15:04:59.771989+0000","level":"info","message":"handler output","handler":{"type":"pipe","command":"handler-slack.rb","severites":["critical","unknown"],"name":"slack"},"output":["only handling every 180 occurrences: sensu-server-client-test/disk\n"]}
```

I get a remote sensu client running and connected and I then deliberately stop the remote client server to produce `warning` and `critical` events from the `keepalive` checks. I would like a message to be sent to my slack channel however nothing is being sent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look in /var/log/sensu/sensu-server.log after a restart and/or after a check. If sensu finds an error, it just ignores it but it is at least logged.

Comment: @Kobbe I added an entry of the sensu-server.log. I only see info level logs in there, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Simple error, changed the following:

```
"command": "/usr/local/bin/handler-slack.rb",
```

To the following:

```
"command": "handler-slack.rb",
```